# how to load script only for firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there a way to load script file only for FireFox

for example:

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<script src="js/scriptFF.js"></script> - this only for firefox ??
```

UPDATE

I made in this way

```
<script>
    if($.browser.mozilla) { 
        jQuery.getScript("js/scriptFF.js");
    } else {        
        jQuery.getScript("js/scriptAll.js");            
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You could programmatically detect the browsertype (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html), and then programmatically create the script tag loading the correct script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($.browser.mozilla) {
  // do something
}
```

for versions

```
if ($.browser.mozilla && $.browser.version >= "2.0" ){
   alert('Mozilla above 1.9');
}
```

[**jQuery Browser**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Answer (score 6):

You can create a `<script>` tag dynamically checking based on `User Agent`.

```
var ffFlag = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') !== -1);
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = (ffFlag)?"js/scriptFF.js":"js/script.js";
script.type = "text/javascript";
```

This should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Into your code, add :

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)
{
    //Your firefox code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, although if someone is spoofing their user agent you might come unstuck:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') !== -1) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "js/scriptFF.js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
}
```